# C# Project can't find reference despite HintPath and ReferencePath in csproj

Tags: c#, reference, com, csproj

I am upgrading libraries in a C# project.
So far I placed the new reference and used csproj HintPath or ReferencePath to point to them.

But for that particular dll it is not working ; "Path" in VS remains empty.

Below is the the dll code in csproj.
The structure looks a bit different from the one I have done previously: ComReference rather than Reference, Guid, WrapperTool etc

```
<ItemGroup>
 <COMReference Include="XXX">
  <Guid>{XXXX-XX-XX-XX}</Guid>
  <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
  <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
  <Lcid>0</Lcid>
  <WrapperTool>XXX</WrapperTool>
  <Isolated>False</Isolated>
  <EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>
  <ReferencePath>C:\Libraries\XXX.dll</ReferencePath>
 </COMReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Do you know what could be wrong?
Also if it was a issue with version compatibility, would I still see the path and get a compile error afterwards?

Comment: Be sure to quote the *exact* error message you see when trying to build this project.

Comment: This is the error I get C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(2701, 5) : warning MSB3287: Cannot load type library for reference "XXX". Error loading type Library/dll. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))